# Drupal WYSIWG bar not showing for populated fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, wysiwyg

When I edit a page, the body WYSIWYG field shows as a textarea with the HTML content inside. This only happens for pages with content in that field, else a WYSIWYG field with no content is shown successfully. Hitting 'Edit summary', which is also empty, does show the WYSIWYG options.

[image: WYSIWYG showing for empty field only]

The text format is set to Full HTML, so that it shows correctly on the front end.

[image: text format full HTML]

I do have a warning and a couple of errors:

```
[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

jquery-1.8.3.min.js - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

I recently moved this Drupal site from AWS to a simple WHM / Cpanel server, but I don't know what's different. I am not overly familiar with Drupal. The ckeditor plugin seems to be installed.

I have tried lowering the jQuery version, flushing the cache etc. Litespeed cache is running, but not when logged in.

---

**Drupal: 7.56**

**CKEditor: 4.4.5.1**

---

**Update:** By removing the async from the ajax call, I removed the warning. But any simple ajax call I make, with no data etc. to a completely new function that only echo's out some text still returns a 404.

**Update 2:** I can remove the AJAX XSS check and the WYSIWYG shows, but I think the issues is wider, in that all AJAX across the site seems to be broken. Paginated links don't work across the site.

Comment: Please try installing CKEditor in your Drupal 7 according to this guide: https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal/Open_Source/Drupal_7. If it helps I will post it as answer.

Comment: It's already in /sites/libraries/ckeditor. I can even reach config pages for ckeditor, if I try and upload it via the Drupal UI it says it's already installed, and it was previously working on a different server. I should have mentioned that I have tried the basics like following the documentation.